# putch argument makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, stdio

in my following program, I get an error that "passing argument 1 of 'putch' makes integer from pointer without a cast" if I use 'putch' to print blank space.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int row,i,spc;
    for(row=1;row<=5;++row)
    {
        for(spc=5;spc>row;--spc)
        putch(" ");
        for(i=1;i<=row;++i)
        printf("%d",i);
        puts("\n");
    }
}
```

I wonder what does it mean here by 'int' while ' ' is a character. Isn't it?
Or am I missing something?

Comment: `' '` is an integer, yes. But `" "` is a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder what does it mean here by 'int' while ' ' is a character.

Your source code contains `" "`, but your question here contains `' '`. You should be aware of the difference: Computers do not intuit what you mean. If you type quotation marks, that means something different than if you type apostrophes.

No, `' '` is not a character. In the terms of the C standard, it is an *integer character constant*. Its type is `int`.

`" "` is a *string literal*. It specifies a static array of 2 `char` that is initialized to contain the space character and the null character. When used as the argument of a function call, the array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Hence `putchar(" ")` attempts to pass this pointer to `putchar`, but `putchar` requires an `int` argument.

Answer (score 0):

As [AlexP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7412986/alexp) already mentioned in his comment,you need to use a simple quoting like [this](https://www.c-lang.thiyagaraaj.com/tutorials/c-data-input-and-ouput/single-character-output-function-:-putch()):

```
char ch = ' ';

putch(ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters do not use non-standard C functions or macros like `putch` and headers like `<conio.h>`.

Instead of the function `putch` you can use the standard function `putchar`.

Also according to the C standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

In this call

```
putch(" ");
```

the function argument is a string literal that has the type `char[2]` and defined like

```
{ ' ', '\n' }
```

Used as an argument it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first character.

It is the reason of the error. Instead of passing an argument of the type int like

```
putch( ' ' );
```

you are passing an argument of the type `char *` due to the implicit conversion of the string literal to pointer.

Also try to declare variables in the scope where they are used. Otherwise it is difficult to read programs with numerous declarations of variables in the beginning of the program because their purposes are unclear.

You could output your pattern using only two loops.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );

        int n;

        if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 || n <= 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            int value = 1;
            printf( "%*d", n - i, value );

            while ( !( i < value++ ) ) printf( "%d", value );

            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 9

        1
       12
      123
     1234
    12345
   123456
  1234567
 12345678
123456789

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 8

       1
      12
     123
    1234
   12345
  123456
 1234567
12345678

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7

      1
     12
    123
   1234
  12345
 123456
1234567

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 6

     1
    12
   123
  1234
 12345
123456

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

    1
   12
  123
 1234
12345

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

   1
  12
 123
1234

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

  1
 12
123

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

 1
12

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Comment: “For starters do not use non-standard C functions or macros like putch and headers like <conion.h>” Any reason for this? cuz I’m a beginner. so lemme comprehend it better!